# How to using c# to create folder on ubuntu server?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, directory

I have a ubuntu server and I want to create a repository remotely by passing the DNS and the name of the name.

I used : Seems to take the local path of my C:/ so not working :

```
Directory.CreateDirectory($@"{someDnsOrIp}\testFolder\");
```

Comment: _"On Unix systems, use a forward slash (/) as path separator."_ => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-7.0

Comment: Is that supposed to be a UNC Path?

Comment: @Fildor Not a UNC because it's a virtual marchine where I want to create the folder

Comment: I think you might want to investigate "Path": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-7.0 It will format the path according to the environment.

Comment: @VicF What I did : When creating my docker container in the Ubuntu server, I passed in the container volume :  /projects/_storage/data:/storage. And then when I create the directory, I just pass the volume folder and it's worked for me. Hope it helps